# self-signed SSL certificate using AFNetworking 2.3.1

Tags: ios, ssl, afnetworking-2

I'm trying to use a self-signed certificate `.cer` in my iOS app. I followed this nice tutorial :
http://initwithfunk.com/blog/2014/03/12/afnetworking-ssl-pinning-with-self-signed-certificates/

I added my .cer file tu the project. 
And init my AFHTTPRequestOperationManager :

```
self.securityPolicy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeCertificate];
self.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
```

But I always get this -1012 error :

> Error The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error
>   -1012.)

I checked the `+ (NSArray *)defaultPinnedCertificates` its correctly load my `.cer`.

but `evaluateServerTrust:forDomain:` always return NO :

`return trustedCertificateCount == [serverCertificates count];`

`[serverCertificates count]` = 2 and `trustedCertificateCount` = 1.

What does this means? Can you help me please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AFSecurityPolicy`'s default behaviour is to validate the certificate chain. You should add all intermediate certificates, or disable validation of the chain:

`self.securityPolicy.validatesCertificateChain = NO;`

Adding intermediate certificates is the preferred approach.

Comment: Thanks this works. We decided to keep only the leaf check system in order to allow server side certificate renew without app re submission.

Comment: You might find `AFSSLPinningModePublicKey` helpful for this situation, if certificate is renewed with the same keys